# Android Manage SQLite database connection

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have an app that use a sqlite database. For every query (10 query selects in 10 differents methods) i open the database. It is a good choice to open db when the application is started and close it when application close? For example, creating an static reference to my DB object in MyApplication class (extends Application).

Thanks for your advices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a static singleton which keeps references to the db and other oft-used resources, such as this:

```
class Global {
    private static SQLiteDatabase _db = null;

    public static SQLiteDatabase getDb() {
        if( _db == null ) {
            ... assign & open _db
        }

        return _db;
    }
}
```

Elsewhere, just reference `Global.getDb()`